# Debian 8 XFCE Evince has no extended menu or hotkeys

Tags: debian, xfce, evince

How can I access the full menu in the Evince PDF viewer in Debian 8 with XFCE?

It is also not accepting any hotkeys such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to search the document.

[image: evince]
[image: evince loaded]

Comment: There should be a icon with multiple horizontal lines, sometimes called a hamburger menu. But this doesn't show unless you select a file. You can do this at the command line "evince filename.pdf". Evince no longer has much by way of menu items, unfortunately. However, okular is an option.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I added a screenshot with a document open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by removing the default evince and installing the evince-gtk package.

[image: evince-gtk]

Comment: Yes, that is, as it turns out, the version I use. I'm not sure why they look different. Sorry I wasn't any help.